# Angular Scope not working in onclick function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem here where the correct $scope.testMessage is not being passed into QB.chat.send...

Right now what happens when typing new info into the input field tied to $scope.testMessage is an update to the {{testMessage}} in the HTML, which is what we expect, but when punching the button tied to sendMessageClick(), this new value isn't passed into the function -- the old value, here set to "Cheese" is passed into it. Even if it has been changed to "StinkingFrenchCheese" and that is reflected in the {{testMessage}} part on the live HTML. It still only passes "Cheese" to the sendMessageClick.

```js
  $scope.testMessage = "Cheese";
  console.log($scope.testMessage);

  $scope.sendMessageClick = function() {


    console.log("message  = " + $scope.testMessage);

    var user = $rootScope.user;
    console.log('sendMessageclick');
    var countchew = "3354163-23837@chat.quickblox.com"; //countchew
    var starshipenterprise = "3354099-23837@chat.quickblox.com"; //starshipenterprise
    if (user == "countchew"){
      QB.chat.roster.confirm(starshipenterprise, function(){
        console.log("roster.confirm called");
      });
      QB.chat.roster.add(starshipenterprise, function() {
        console.log("roster.add called");
      });
      var chewparams = {type: 'chat', name: 'testMessage', body: ($scope.testMessage), extension: {save_to_history: 1}};
      QB.chat.send(starshipenterprise, chewparams);
    } else if (user == "starshipenterprise"){
      QB.chat.roster.confirm(countchew, function() {
        console.log("roster.confirm called");
      });
      QB.chat.roster.add(countchew, function() {
        console.log("roster.add called");
      });
      var starparams = {type: 'chat', name: 'testMessage', body: ($scope.testMessage), extension: {save_to_history: 1}};
      QB.chat.send(countchew, starparams);
    }

  };
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Chat">
  <ion-content>

    <center class="padding-vertical">Chat 'em up</center>
      
      <!-- Begin Login Form -->
      <div class="list list-inset">


          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" ng-model="user.username">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
          </label>
          <button class="button button-full button-balanced" data-ng-click="signInClick()">
           Sign In
          </button>


          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Input your message!" ng-model="inputMessage">
          </label>
          <button class="button button-full button-balanced" data-ng-click="sendMessageClick()">
           Send your message
          </button>
          <button class="button button-full button-balanced" data-ng-click="getCurrentParseUser()">
           Get Current Parse User
          </button>
          <button class="button button-full button-balanced" data-ng-click="QBDisconnect()">
           Disconnect from QB chat
          </button>     


          <p>The message is : {{testMessage}}</p>
          <p>Debug area says : {{debug}}</p>

          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Give some text!" ng-model="testMessage">
          </label>
          <button class="button button-full button-balanced" data-ng-click="sendMessageClick()">
           Send your message
          </button>

       </div>
      <!-- End Login Form -->

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I think after running `QB.chat` events you need to run digest cycle inside there callback..

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: AFAIK `QB.chat` events are running outside the angular context..so the digest cycle won't get run for them..in order to make binding workable you need to use `$scope.$apply()` inside each callback function of events that will make it working

Comment: Ah interesting - only problem is there are no callbacks with QB.chat.send - just fire and forget. Do you mean I should put it in the if statement?

Comment: Nope :0 this didn't work. I put it in the top of the sendMessageClick and got an error that apply was already active,

then I put it in each of the parts of the if statement, and no error like that, but also same behavior as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the message to the on click handler:

```
  <button class="button button-full button-balanced" data-ng-click="sendMessageClick(testMessage)">
```

Then have your onclick handler receive the new message as the input

```
  $scope.sendMessageClick = function(msg) {
```

Comment: I need an option that isn't hardcoded but takes the input from the input field

Comment: it's not hard coded, testMessage is bound to the input as the model, right?

Comment: yeah I'm getting around to it

Comment: Yeah I Think this will probably work but QuickBlox is being difficult so I can't actually test it right now, but when I do I'll make sure to accept it if it works.

Comment: Actually just realized I can do a console.log of the params which should be enough here you go!

Comment: can you say why it was broken the way it was?

Comment: I do not know QB, but it looks like their implementation for the function calls that you are making is async (probably async ajax call?). In Angular, if you perform an non-angular async op (the simplest example is setTimeout) you would have to let the angular digest cycle know about it. This is usually done either by calling $scope.$apply over the callback code, or by using built in angular services that internally do the same thing (so $timeout instead of setTimeout, $http instead of async ajax, etc.)